# CDN or download into directory?

Tags: cdn

Haven't found many resources for this - If I wanted to use jQuery in my app, for example, would it be more beneficial to download jQuery into my project's directory, or to link the google CDN for use?

Comment: Each way has its own benefits.

Comment: Naturally, I wasn't looking for a direct winner.

Comment: Your wording suggests that you were. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDN -
**Less Latency**

> Using a CDN: Using a CDN helps bring resources closer to the user by
>   caching them in multiple locations around the world. Once those
>   resources are cached, a user’s request only needs to travel to the
>   closest Point of Presence to retrieve that data instead of going back
>   to the origin server each time.

Without CDN - **Offline test localhost**

> You can test your website on your local machine without network
>   connectivity if you serve your libraries locally while in development.

Without CDN **Monkey Patching**

> You can modify and fix certain issues in a library that create
>   breaking issues in your software and host these. If you use a CDN you
>   will have to use the original library's code instead thus losing these
>   fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the response - That's what I was looking for.